# positioning divs after each other on a responsive layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this html and css :

```
<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
     <div id="busqueda">
         content
      </div>
    This is column 1

    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    This is column 2
<div id="busqueda">
         content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    This is column 3
<div id="busqueda">
         content
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 { width: 100%; }
.span_2_of_3 { width: 66.13%; }
.span_1_of_3 { width: 32.26%; }

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}
```

My problem is that then i have several divs inside each .span and when i resize the window they overlap , i'd want them to stack , one below another when i resize the window the css for that div is :

```
#busqueda {
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  border: 5px solid #6D6D6D;
  padding: 19px;
  font-family: 'trebuchet ms';
  font-style: oblique;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  border-radius: 13px;
  margin-right: 55%;
  border-color:#fd8a17;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

any ideas what i should do to make that happen ? i've tried floating them to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your html for the first column is somehow different from the other two.
So I made the adjust here: https://jsfiddle.net/qrbcf8ne/1/
Here is the code to the change, and I also add one more div in each span:

```
<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">This is column 1
        <div id="busqueda">content11</div>
        <div id="busqueda">content22</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">This is column 2
        <div id="busqueda">content21</div>
        <div id="busqueda">content22</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">This is column 3
        <div id="busqueda">content31</div>
        <div id="busqueda">content32</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's exactly right ! , just what i wanted , just a quick question if i want everything to resize at diffent points i should just add another @media with another size right? right know this happens and it's kind of a bother http://imgur.com/6b0PBul

Comment: In general that's right. In your example, if you make each column in a row to 33% (with box-sizing: border-box), it shouldn't overlap. But 33% is not always good when screen size gets smaller, so you need to define break point based on screen size when the page looks bad. That's where @media comes into play.